# How to set up DMZ?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I have two routers (one generic ZTE mobile router from my ISP and TP-Link Archer C7 that I use as an access point). My computer is connected throught ethernet to my second router (Archer C7) and all of the wireless devices in the house are also connected to it (because it has much bigger range than our ZTE router). I tried to set up port forwarding so I can remotly access my bit torrent client. I port forwarded on port 9091 on my ZTE router but it didn't work. I've read some stuff online and I saw many suggestions that this could be done with DMZ but my knowledge of the matter is very limited.Both of my routers have NAT enabled and I have a dynamic IP address. Does anyone know how could I set this up?

Comment: You should look at the results coming back from searching for "bit torrent port", including [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33983/what-are-the-tcp-udp-ports-used-by-torrent-applications). I can't find a reference to the use of port 9091, but you should check what port your torrent program is using, with an appropriate network command for your OS. I see no reason for needing a DMZ, but you will need to set this in the ZTE router if you do, provided it's supported.

Comment: DMZ is supported and this is not just the bit torrent issue that was just the most recent example. I've been having problems with many other applications like port forwarding for video games etc.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit more?  I guess you have (ISP) ↔ (generic ZTE mobile router) ↔ (TP-Link Archer C7 router) ↔ (all your other devices), but you never actually spell that out.  (I suspect that the fact that your computer connects to the Archer C7 by Ethernet cable, while other devices connect to it wirelessly, will not be important.)  Where and what is your “bit torrent client”?  (I guess this is a program on your computer(?).)  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  I guess when you say “remotly” you mean from outside your household. Does your household (the ZTE router) have a fixed IP address?   Are both of your routers doing NAT?  Is IPv6 an option? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @AFH Port 9091 is used, at least, by Transmission for the remote control interface. There's a different port for connections (random ports also work).

Comment: @Nenad DMZ, which stands for "DeMilitarized Zone" is used when you want to give direct access to a given device. The router connecting to the internet (ZTE, supposedly) is the one that must support that feature (DMZ). The point is being able to allow unrestricted access to the other one (TP-Link) so that the port forwarding rules needed can be set on that one only. If the ZTE does not have that feature but can do port forwarding you'll need two sets of rules, one for each device. That won't be easy to setup if you don't quite understand this concepts.

Comment: @MichaelBay The ZTE router (that is connected to the internet) supports DMZ. How exactly do I set that up?

Comment: Enable DMZ for the other router's internal IP address, that's all.

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried doing that (I enabled DMZ on ZTE router for IP 192.168.0.23 which is the IP of my second router) and on the second router I port forwarded on port 9091 on IP address on which my computer is but it still doesn't work

Comment: @MichaelBay I tried scanning the port and it says it is closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75847/discussion-between-michaelbay-and-nenad).

Comment: "I port forwarded on port 9091 on my ZTE router but it didn't work"  Forwarded it to where?  How did you configure the forwarding?  If you have two NAT routers in a row, you'll need to forward the port from router 1 to router 2, and then forward the port from router 2 to the server.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 So I just portforward on port 9091 to my second router (192.168.0.23) and than on that router I port forward on port 9091 to my computer (192.168.0.109)?

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't be using the same subnet on both sides of router 2 (192.168.0.X).  Wan IP/subnet -> Router 1 -> LAN subnet 1 -> Router 2 -> LAN subnet 2.